# How to build a loops for gdal WriteArray()?

Tags: python, gdal

I feel the gdal WriteArray() is so tedious.First, `Create(file)`,then `prj`, last `WtriteArray(arr)`. Now the problem is how to write many rasters? Because it need to create file first and then write array. How to build a loop for variable `arr`? For example:
now I got some array varaibe r1, r2, r3....

```
driver=gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff')
outfilename=['r1.tif','r2.tif','r3.tif'......]
for filename in outfilename:
    outfile=os.path.join(outpath,filename)
    outdataset=driver.Create(outfile,cols,rows,1,3)
    geotran=data0.GetGeoTransform()                     
    outdataset.SetGeoTransform(geotran)           
    proj = data.GetProjection()
    outdataset.SetProjection(proj)
    outband=outdataset.GetRasterBand(1)
    outband.SetNoDataValue(-32768)
    outband.WriteArray(r1)          #how to build the loop in this line?
    outband=None
    outdataset=None
print('Done')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Rasterio](https://mapbox.github.io/rasterio/) is great, and @sgillies answer is the one to follow if you want a modern python solution. This answer is for the case that you want to use GDAL without the modern wrapper.

If the output images have the same dimensions and footprint, then the best idea might be to use the `CreateCopy` function of `gdal.Driver`. It will create a copy of an existing dataset and retain the geospatial information, no data value, and other metadata. This makes the inner loop only need to create a new dataset and write the array, resulting in much cleaner code.
**CreateCopy only works if the datatype and number of bands are the same in the source and destination datasets.**

```
import gdal
# ...

data0 = gdal.Open('original.tif', gdal.GA_ReadOnly)
driver = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff')

# process/create arrays
arrays = {'r1': np.ndarray(), 'r2': np.ndarray(), ...}

# loop through arrays
for name, arr in arrays.items():
    ds = driver.CreateCopy(name + '.tif', data0)
    ds.GetRasterBand(1).WriteArray(arr)
    ds = None
```

Answer (score 3):

I wrote [Rasterio](https://mapbox.github.io/rasterio/quickstart.html) to make writing these kinds of programs much less tedious. Also shown here is how to loop over a sequence of 2-D arrays using `enumerate()`.

```
# To explode a multi-band raster file into single band files, read the source's
# bands as a 3-D numpy array and get a copy of its `profile`.

with rasterio.open('example.tif') as source:
    source_data = source.read()
    profile = source.profile

# `profile` is a dict of all the parameters that define the layout of a raster
# file: height, width, band count, data type, nodata value. To create single
# band output files, update the band count to 1.

profile['count'] = 1

# Loop over arrays in source_data and write each to its own file.

for i, arr in enumerate(source_data, 1):
    with rasterio.open('r{}.tif'.format(i), 'w', **profile) as dst:
        dst.write(arr, 1)
```

Comment: Thx! code is conciser when using rasterio. Could I write a 10 bands(arr) to  a raster dataset one time? Or write arr one by one through a loop ? How to re-open a tif dataset and add new bands to it？

Answer (score 0):

You should loop over the arrays that you have in your memory. I have done this by storing multiple arrays in a dictionary and then looped over the keyes.

for key in arrayDict:

...create rasters 
...and write them with outRaster.WriteArray(key).

Or have I missed the point of the question completely.

Comment: Ok. It looks like using a Dict as the dynamic variable in python.